# Python Requests - Deny if not TLS1.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, python-requests, tls1.2

As part of our information security teams requirements, for each API I `POST` or `GET` from/to can I deny the connection if it is not TLS1.2?

This is one that I am using at the moment for `POST` I also need to know how to do it with `GET`:

```
##POST
def retry_session(retries, session=None, backoff_factor=0.3, status_forcelist=(500, 502, 503, 504)):
    session = session or requests.Session()
    retry = Retry(
        total=retries,
        read=retries,
        connect=retries,
        backoff_factor=backoff_factor,
        status_forcelist=status_forcelist,
    )
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
    session.mount('http://', adapter)
    session.mount('https://', adapter)
    return session 

post_response = session.post(url=endpoint, data=json.dumps(x), headers=headers)
```

--

```
##GET
def response(changeset):     
    logging.info("Bringing in JSON from LinzAPI")
    d = requests.get(changeset, stream=True).json()
    return (d)

json_response = response(API)
```

I need to edit my code so that I will only POST or GET to/from a URL if it is TLS1.2

Comment: I think you're just asking for [Specific SSL Version](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#example-specific-ssl-version) in the examples section of the docs?

Comment: I cannot see what the requirement of only TLS 1.2 has to do with your code which does not care about TLS protocol versions at all. Therefore I've marked the question as *unclear what you're asking*.

Comment: If there is a need to only accept TLS 1.2, it should be done at the server (apache or nginx or whatever http servers) level than at the application level.